# Search column for text value, if value exists check other column for number of days from the date today?

Tags: excel, vba, date, count

I have an Excel spreadsheet like so:

```
A               B     
27/03/2015      Riddor
28/03/2015      Text
09/03/2015      Bees
```

What I am trying to do is search my column B for the word `Riddor` using this function:

```
=IF(ISERROR(MATCH("Riddor",Statistics!B:B,0)),"No Match",TODAY()-MIN(Statistics!B:B))
```

Within this function if the value `Riddor` is not found I want to show 'no match' else if the value is found I want to identify the most recent occurrence of the value `Riddor` in my column where its date in column A is the most recent from today. I then want to count the number of days.

So for instance my value `Riddor` in column B has a date of 27/03/2015. The number of days from this date to today is 5, however if I add another `Riddor` with a more recent date like so:

```
27/03/2015
31/03/2015
```

then I want my day count to show 1 day instead of the previous 5 days.

Can someone please show me where I am going wrong and what to do to get this working?

Answer (score 0):

You will need to use a formula as defined below

Note that the flower brackets indicate that you are using this as a range formula which means you will need to hit Shift+Control+Enter and when you click on that Cell it will create the flower brackets in the end.

The below formula will retrieve the `MAX Date` the next part is quite simple you need to subtract from today to arrive at the difference in days. Preferably do it in another cell. I have accounted for different sheets in a modified formula at the bottom of this post. But you can test the below on the same sheet and then copy over the cell to another sheet to have it dynamically correct to account for sheet if you like. Either ways the below is tested with all events and is working

`{=IF(COUNTIF(B:B,"Riddor")=0,"No Match",IF(COUNTIF(B:B,"Riddor")=1,INDIRECT("A"&MATCH("Riddor",B:B,0)),MAX(IF(B:B="Riddor",A:A))))}`

**Explanation** 
**Part I -** `=IF(COUNTIF(B:B,"Riddor")=0,"No Match"` Counts if there are any occurance of the word Riddor in that Range

**Part II -** `IF(COUNTIF(B:B,"Riddor")=1,INDIRECT("A"&MATCH("Riddor",B:B,0))` this part accounts if there is only once occurance of the word Riddor then it uses the Match function to retrieve the date from the A Column. It would be easier with VLOOKUP but I'm assuming you dont want to change the Column Order for A & B

**Part III -** `MAX(IF(B:B="Riddor",A:A))))` This where the Range formula is actually required. It checks in the Range B:B and Retrieves all the Dates where the B Column Matches "Riddor" and then Finds the Max date in that subset Range which would be the date closest to today's date.

**Tested and Working perfectly in sample provided by your even with Multiple instances of Riddor.**

Formula Accounting for the difference in Sheets not tested yet.

`{=IF(COUNTIF(Statistics!B:B,"Riddor")=0,"No Match",IF(COUNTIF(Statistics!B:B,"Riddor")=1,INDIRECT("Statistics!A"&MATCH("Riddor",Statistics!B:B,0)),MAX(IF(Statistics!B:B="Riddor",Statistics!A:A))))}`

Comment: thanks for this code, i have tried this but instead of 6 days it gives me 42095 days? have you tested this and it is working for you?

Comment: Its not 42095 days, if you convert that to date format dd-mmm-yy its actually a date 42095 is the Excel interpretation of 01-Apr-2015 if you subtract that from today's date (Insert `=Today()` in another cell and subtract the two cells) you'll get the correct answer you are looking for.

Comment: thanks your code kind of works but if there is a different value in the same column b as my riddor then it still counts the days of non riddor values